# how can i move cursor to a specific field through jquery on form?

Tags: jquery, html, cursor

i am having a `form` where the first field is `dropdown`, contains options like `student` and `employee`. and below there are two text fields for `college name` and `company name`.

if a person selects `student` then `college name` text box should be `enabled` and `company name` text box should be disabled, and if a person clicks `employee` then `company field` should be `enabled` and `college field` should be `disabled`.

and the `cursor` focus should `automatically` move to a `particular field` based on the user selection of dropdown.(example upon student selection `company` should be `disabled` and the `cursor` focus should point to the `college` field. and vice versa) how can i do this?

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row main">
    <div class="panel-heading">
             <div class="panel-title text-center">
                <h1 class="title">Company Name</h1>
                <hr />
              </div>
          </div> 
    <div class="main-login main-center">
      <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="#">

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">I am a</label>
          <div class="cols-sm-10">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                <select name="cars">
                  <option value="volvo">Student</option>
                  <option value="saab">Employee</option>

                </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">College Name</label>
          <div class="cols-sm-10">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email"  placeholder="Enter your Email"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="username" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Company Name</label>
          <div class="cols-sm-10">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username"  placeholder="Enter your Username"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group ">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block login-button">Register</button>
        </div>
        <div class="login-register">
                <a href="index.php">Login</a>
             </div>
      </form>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $(selector).focus() function with the appropriate if else condition to solve the problem. Hope It helps.
Here the selector can be chosen using appropriate class or id.

Comment: Thanks for reply. for example if there is a big paragraph description is present immeadi on the page after the select dropdown. beacause of this the college name and employee   field are present in very bottom of the page. in that case based on the select option i want to scroll that field to the top automatically through jquery. how can i do that?

Comment: You want that field to get selected? Give those fields an id. Use ("#id").focus()  to scroll to that option. After that the drop-down list will appear once you click enter. It will serve the require purpose. If you feel the scroll is not at appropriate place we have ("id").scroll() function which will work for you perfectly.